# How do I instantiate parameterized versions of generic designs in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to understand generic programming in VHDL and I've written some simple code to be able to do so. My goal is to be able to write a generic design (generic in the sense that certain things like input/output size of an entity are not specified) and then instantiate it in a top-level module and specify the design constraints at instantiation. This way, I can write a single design to satisfy many different parameter constraints depending on the needs of the user. Otherwise, I would need to write a separate design for each file where only a few modifications are made in each. An obvious use case for this sort of flexibility would be in creating a library.

These two files illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
-- array_adder.vhd
-- 
-- Computes and outputs the pointwise addition of two arrays.
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package array_adder_pkg is
    generic (array_size     : integer;
             precision_size : integer
    );
    type array_type is array (0 to array_size-1) of signed(precision_size-1 downto 0);

    component array_adder is
        port (a   : in  array_type;
              b   : in  array_type;
              c   : out array_type
        );
    end component;
end package;
-----main code:-----------------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity array_adder is
    port (a : in  array_type;
          b : in  array_type;
          c : out array_type
    );
end entity;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
architecture fpga of array_adder is
begin
    comp: for i in 0 to array_size-1 generate
        c(i) <= a(i) + b(i);
    end generate;
end architecture;
```

and

```
-- top_level.vhd
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
package small_pkg is new work.array_adder_pkg
    generic map (array_size     => 3,
                 precision_size => 5
    );
package large_pkg is new work.array_adder_pkg
    generic map (array_size     => 15,
                 precision_size => 9
    );
use work.small_pkg.all;
use work.large_pkg.all;

library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity top_level is
end entity;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
architecture fpga of top_level is
    signal small_ina : work.small_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(1, work.small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(2, work.small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(3, work.small_pkg.precision_size));
    signal small_inb : work.small_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(4, work.small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(5, work.small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(6, work.small_pkg.precision_size));
    signal small_out : work.small_pkg.array_type;

    signal large_ina : work.large_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(100, work.large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(110, work.large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(120, work.large_pkg.precision_size));
    signal large_inb : work.large_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(50, work.large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(30, work.large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(80, work.large_pkg.precision_size));
    signal large_out : work.large_pkg.array_type;
begin
    small_array_adder: work.small_pkg.array_adder
        port map (a => small_ina,
                  b => small_inb,
                  c => small_out);

    large_array_adder: work.large_pkg.array_adder
        port map (a => large_ina,
                  b => large_inb,
                  c => large_out);
end architecture;
```

This first set doesn't compile because `array_adder` doesn't know what `array_type` is. In ModelSim 10.4b, I get `(vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "array_type".` That's not surprising, since I never instantiated the `array_adder_pkg`.

So, I tried to instantiate a default package in `array_adder.vhd`, which is mostly the same, but I'll include it to be complete. `top_level.vhd` stays the same.

```
-- array_adder2.vhd
-- 
-- Computes and outputs the pointwise addition of two arrays.
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package array_adder_pkg is
    generic (array_size     : integer;
             precision_size : integer
    );
    type array_type is array (0 to array_size-1) of signed(precision_size-1 downto 0);

    component array_adder is
        port (a   : in  array_type;
              b   : in  array_type;
              c   : out array_type
        );
    end component;
end package;
-----main code:-----------------------------------------------------------------
package default_array_adder_pkg is new work.array_adder_pkg
    generic map (array_size     => 3,
                 precision_size => 7
    );
use work.default_array_adder_pkg.all;

library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity array_adder is
    port (a : in  array_type;
          b : in  array_type;
          c : out array_type
    );
end entity;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
architecture fpga of array_adder is
begin
    comp: for i in 0 to array_size-1 generate
        c(i) <= a(i) + b(i);
    end generate;
end architecture;
```

Now both files compile, but when I try to simulate `top_level.vhd` in ModelSim I get the error `Fatal: (vsim-3714) At array depth 1, array lengths do not match. Left is 15 (0 to 14). Right is 3 (0 to 2).` which seems to indicate that ModelSim is having trouble with instantiation sizes different than the default. To test this further, I removed the second package instantiation and all code associated with it in `top_level.vhd` (i.e. all the `large_pkg` stuff and the component instantiation associated with it). I'll spare you the mostly redundant code this time. Again, this compiles as expected, but when I attempt to simulate it I get `Fatal: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port "a".`

The only way I can actually get this to work is to use the default package in the top-level design and forego two different sized instantiations, but this defeats the point of a generic design since I will need to write a separate design file for each set of parameter specifications.

Is there another way to do this that I'm missing? Or, is this not something that VHDL currently supports?

Comment: Too Broad. Can you ask a specific question about a [mcve] that exhibits a specific problem?  All your shown code examples have problems, not necessarily the same set. For example with use clauses making declarations for small_pkg and large_pkg then neither of the declarations for types array_type should be directly visible. (IEEE Std 1076-2008 12.4 Use clauses, para 8 case c) ). Match the error messages  and code better. It looks like array_adder is using a different array_type declaration, each is unique and both must used the same declaration.

Comment: the modelsim error is quite evident... for `large_pkg` you set `array_size` to 15... However, you initialize the array with only 3 elements.. and not 15... Do you expect modelsim to randomly fill in the blanks? Modelsim cannot read your mind...

Comment: generic and instantiated packages are 2008 features, as is 5.3.2.1 unbounded array definition, which allows you to defer providing a constraint in the array element subtype indication until declaring an object of the type as well as supplying (an) unconstrained index(es). This would allow you to do away with instantiating generic packages entirely by providing large/small unique generics where the large array and small array adders are instantiated. unconstrained array definitions with a required element subtype constraint were available in -1993 and -2002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, but needed to assign default values to the component in your package.

Then VHDL-2008 allows for unconstrained arrays, which can help you here.

See this example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

package array_pkg is
    type signed_array is array (natural range <>) of signed;
end package;


use work.array_pkg.signed_array;

package array_adder_pkg is
    generic(
        array_size     : positive;
        precision_size : positive
    );

    subtype array_type is signed_array(0 to array_size-1)(precision_size-1 downto 0);

    component array_adder is
        generic(
            array_size     : positive := array_size;
            precision_size : positive := precision_size
        );
        port (
            a : in  signed_array(0 to array_size-1)(precision_size-1 downto 0);
            b : in  signed_array(0 to array_size-1)(precision_size-1 downto 0);
            c : out signed_array(0 to array_size-1)(precision_size-1 downto 0)
        );
    end component;
end package;


use work.array_pkg.signed_array;

entity array_adder is
    generic(
        array_size     : positive;
        precision_size : positive
    );
    port (
        a : in  signed_array(0 to array_size-1)(precision_size-1 downto 0);
        b : in  signed_array(0 to array_size-1)(precision_size-1 downto 0);
        c : out signed_array(0 to array_size-1)(precision_size-1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

library ieee;

architecture fpga of array_adder is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
begin
    comp: for i in 0 to array_size-1 generate
        c(i) <= a(i) + b(i);
    end generate;
end architecture;


entity top_level is end entity;

package small_pkg is new work.array_adder_pkg
    generic map (array_size     => 3,
                 precision_size => 5
    );
package large_pkg is new work.array_adder_pkg
    generic map (array_size     => 3,
                 precision_size => 9
    );

library ieee;

architecture fpga of top_level is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    signal small_ina : work.small_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(1, work.small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(2, work.small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(3, work.small_pkg.precision_size));
    signal small_inb : work.small_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(4, work.small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(5, work.small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(6, work.small_pkg.precision_size));
    signal small_out : work.small_pkg.array_type;

    signal large_ina : work.large_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(100, work.large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(110, work.large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(120, work.large_pkg.precision_size));
    signal large_inb : work.large_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(50, work.large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(30, work.large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(80, work.large_pkg.precision_size));
    signal large_out : work.large_pkg.array_type;
begin
    small_array_adder: work.small_pkg.array_adder
        port map (a => small_ina,
                  b => small_inb,
                  c => small_out);

    large_array_adder: work.large_pkg.array_adder
        port map (a => large_ina,
                  b => large_inb,
                  c => large_out);
end architecture;
```

EDIT: I wanted to add that you can also generate the specialized packages local to your architecture. That way they will not be compiled into your library. Example:

```
entity top_level is end entity;

library ieee;

architecture fpga of top_level is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    package small_pkg is new work.array_adder_pkg
        generic map (array_size     => 3,
                     precision_size => 5
        );
    package large_pkg is new work.array_adder_pkg
        generic map (array_size     => 3,
                     precision_size => 9
        );

    signal small_ina : small_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(1, small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(2, small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(3, small_pkg.precision_size));
    signal small_inb : small_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(4, small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(5, small_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(6, small_pkg.precision_size));
    signal small_out : small_pkg.array_type;

    signal large_ina : large_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(100, large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(110, large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(120, large_pkg.precision_size));
    signal large_inb : large_pkg.array_type :=
                (to_signed(50, large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(30, large_pkg.precision_size),
                 to_signed(80, large_pkg.precision_size));
    signal large_out : large_pkg.array_type;
begin
    small_array_adder: small_pkg.array_adder
        port map (a => small_ina,
                  b => small_inb,
                  c => small_out);

    large_array_adder: large_pkg.array_adder
        port map (a => large_ina,
                  b => large_inb,
                  c => large_out);
end architecture;
```